# What's the difference between const constructor and no_const constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am new to flutter and confused with it's constructor.

For example:

- sample 1:

```
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  const MyContainer({Key key, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

- sample 2:

```
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  MyContainer({this.color});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

I removed `const` and `key` in sample 2, and both of sample1 and sample2 work well.

Is there any potential risk in sample 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a const constructor when you dont want this widget to be rebuild.
A constant widget is like the constant pi, it won't change.
If you have state however you want to use the normal constructor in Sample 2, because the widget changes and cant be constant then.

So you get a slight performance increase when you use const in places where it makes sense (because it wont be rebuild).

The key property is another topic.

Answer (score 2):

***const***

- A variable with the `const` keyword is initialized at `compile-time`
  and is already assigned when at `runtime`.
- You can’t define `const` inside a `class`. But you can in a
  `function`.
- For Flutter specific, everything in the build method won’t be
  initialized again when the state is updated.
- `const` can’t be changed during runtime.

***When to use const?***

-

**`Use const: If you are sure that a value isn’t going to be changed when running your code. For example, when you declare a sentence that always remains the same.`**

Answer (score 0):

when you use const with constructor, it is compile time constant and all values given in constructor must be constant,

try giving unconstant values to const Constuctor to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code snippet in your local env but first you need to import `benchmark_harness` you won't find much of a difference But it will improve the for performance when flutter create widget and elements for the const stateless widget because it won't create element again on rebuild or animations which is memory intensive

```
void main() {
  const ConstObjectBenchMark(32).report();
  const NormalObjectBenchmark(32).report();
}

abstract class Benchmark extends BenchmarkBase {
  const Benchmark(String name) : super(name);

  @override
  void exercise() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
      run();
    }
  }
}

class ConstObjectBenchMark extends Benchmark {
  const ConstObjectBenchMark(this.length) : super('growable[$length]');

  final int length;

  @override
  void run() {
    const constPerson = ConstPerson('Const Person', 30);
  }
}

class NormalObjectBenchmark extends Benchmark {
  const NormalObjectBenchmark(this.length) : super('fixed-length[$length]');

  final int length;

  @override
  void run() {
    final normalPerson = NormalPerson('Const Person', 30);
  }
}

class ConstPerson {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  const ConstPerson(this.name, this.age);
}

class NormalPerson {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  NormalPerson(this.name, this.age);
}
```

output:

[image]